# Cannot use ng-bootstrap with Webpack and Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ng-bootstrap

First I installed and imported the `NgbModule`:

- `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
- `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`

At this point, everything works fine, I'm able to run my application the way it was before `ng-bootstrap`

As soon as I added the `NgbModule` to the `imports` array of my `NgModule`, as described here:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgbModule, ....
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, ....],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

I'm unable to run `npm start` using `webpack-dev-server`, as it shouts :

[image: error]

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/boot",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts/,   loader: ["ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
     ],
     preLoaders: [
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", exclude: ['node_modules', 'ext-*', 'lib', 'tools'] }
    ]
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Any help and explanation would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE:

Removing the usage of `source-map-loader` from the `preLoaders` removes the error, but resulting no Typescript source in browser.

Any idea what to do? and why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like  webpack searches source-map-loader in your local computer files and not in your project.
Therefore my guess would be that 
`npm install source-map-loader --save-dev` won't work.

When some module is asked from your local PC and not from your project, it's probably a module that's supposed to be installed globally.

Try:
`npm install source-map-loader -g`

Answer (score 0):

Is the source-map-loader module installed, ie is it in your node_modules folder? If not install it with this command:

```
npm install source-map-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks for the quick reply. yes the source-map-loader is installed and is present in my `node_modules`

Comment: The weird thing is that this error pops up only when i import that `NgbModule`, without the importing, everything works just fine, but then i cannot use the `ng-bootstrap` of course

Comment: @Cieja Yes I have, please note the accepted answer :)